# How naturally can functions defined by parametric integrals be interpolated from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb R^+$?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, gamma-function

*[This question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/181943/how-naturally-can-functions-defined-by-parametric-integrals-be-interpolated-from) has not got any answer on Mathoverflow. I admit that it is unusual to cross-post in* this *direction (from MO to math.SE), but knowing that some of those really unbelievable integrals tend to be solved (i.e. given in closed form) rather here than on the MO site, I have the hope that some people here will share their insights into integrals by answering these questions.*

It is well known that several definite integrals $I_n$ containing a parameter $n\in\mathbb N$ can be expressed recursively (e.g. doing integration by parts) in terms of $I_{n-1} $  or $I_{n-2} $, and thus written as some expression containing factorials, e.g. the gamma function itself $$\int_0^\infty t^{n}e^{-t}dt=n\int_0^\infty t^{n-1}e^{-t}dt=\cdots=n!$$

Or take the formula $I_n:=\int_0^\pi \sin^nx\;dx=\dfrac{n-1}nI_{n-2}$, allowing to obtain $$\int_0^\pi \sin^{2n}x\;dx=\dfrac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}n!^2}\pi\ \ \text{  and  }\ \int_0^\pi \sin^{2n+1}x\;dx=\dfrac{2^{2n+1}n!^2}{(2n+1)!}$$ (which BTW easily yields the [Wallis product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product#Proof_using_integration.5B2.5D)).

As long as for such integrals the LHS is also defined for non-integer (say all positive real) $n$,

> **is it "automatically" guaranteed that replacing on the RHS $n!$ by $\Gamma(n+1)$ yields a valid formula?**

We all know that the interpolation of the gamma function between the factorials to $\mathbb R$ is not unique but that the [Bohr-Mollerup theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr%E2%80%93Mollerup_theorem) assures a unique extension when adding the mild (?) condition of log-convexity. The problem:  *the LHS expressions above don't "know" anything about log-convexity*...

We can ask a similar question (even though there is no simple recursion formula in this case) about the Riemann zeta function with, for $n>1$, $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^n}{e^t - 1} \; \frac{dt}{t}=\zeta(n) \; \Gamma(n) $$ or, closely related, this interpolation of the [Bernoulli numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Integral_representation_and_continuation) $$ 4n\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{2n}}{e^{2\pi t}-1} \frac{dt}{t}=4n\frac{2^{2n-1}}{2^{2n-1}-1}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{2n}}{e^{2\pi t}+1} \frac{dt}{t}=(-1)^{n+1}B_{2n}$$ or this one of the [Euler numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_number) $$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{2n}}{\cosh\frac{\pi t}2}\; dt =(-1)^{n}E_{2n}.$$ 
The two last ones are somewhat intriguing because for half-integers $n$, the integrals are obviously not $0$, unlike the odd Bernoulli and Euler numbers. For Euler numbers, this can of course be explained by the fact that the "entire" integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ does vanish in this case (odd function), but for the Bernoulli numbers the situation is different.

> **What is going on here?**